# What exactly does one Apache process do?

Tags: apache

I am having a tough time finding an answer to this seemingly simple question. What does one single Apache process handle? Is it one single request from one visitor? Would each asset (image, css file, etc) a visitor downloads require a separate Apache process?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Likely you are using Apache's "prefork MPM" so you have a non-threaded parent process that spawns a number of child processes ("Servers") determined by your configuration ([`StartServers`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mpm_common.html#startservers) determines how many child processes to start at startup, [`MaxClients`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mpm_common.html#maxclients) determines the maximum number of child processes that will be launched to serve requests, etc.). Each Server can handle a number of requests, so each asset does not require a separate process. The setting [`MaxRequestsPerChild`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mpm_common.html#maxrequestsperchild) determines the lifetime of the Server. Setting it to 0 means that the child process will never be expired. If you've got a lot of requests, you'll also probably want to set [`KeepAlive`](http://agiletesting.blogspot.com/2009/01/watch-that-apache-keepalive-setting.html) to On so you're using the same connection to serve multiple requests.

Comment: Thank you sir... very helpful. When you say "Each server can handle a number of requests", I am assuming that means in sequence, as opposed to concurrently... yes?

Comment: Yeah, sequential. Each child has a queue of requests it's going to work through. If you set MaxRequestsPerChild X, that Child will expire after it's served X requests. Concurrency is achieved by having more servers started. You'd be better off dumping the load to another *actual* server though. Like pushing all your resource/asset requests through S3/Cloudfront so your application server is serving mostly application requests. Less memory.